Barbecue scene in a comedy movie with black actors
I have seen a long time ago a comedy movie with some black actors and I can't find it no matter what. I will try to give a description of a scene I remember as best I can.

Barbecue party outside (in an abandon industrial area)
Lots of people including all the main characters 
The main character sees a girl he likes and talks to her, some commotion takes place and we see some people at a table eating. She says the guy that is at the end of the table is her brother who went many times to jail
At the table, we see people pass something under the table (a shank) from one person to another until it reaches the guy at the end (the brother).
He takes the "knife" looks quickly left and right and then starts stabbing his food yelling "bone check, bone check" while covering the "knife"
Back to our main character, near a fence, he opens up a beer and says "this one is for my dead homies" then he pours the beer over the fence. As the camera pans up we see a pile of dead bodies and he pouring the beer on them. 

Sadly this is all the information I can give. Hope it is enough for an identification.

"Black actors" and "comedy" isn't very descriptive. I'd suggest trying to add some more unique details to your title to attract viewers.

Can you specify "long ago"? That could mean something between 5 and 30 years...

You're looking for Don't Be a Menace to South Central While Drinking Your Juice in the Hood (1996).

"Don't Be a Menace to South Central While Drinking your Juice in the Hood" is a parody of several U.S. films about being in the 'Hood', for instance "Boyz n the Hood", "South Central", "Menace II Society", "Higher Learning" and "Juice". We follow Ashtray as he returns to the place he grew up in and meet his father and his basket-case friends. 

You can see most of the barbecue scene you're describing here:




Thank you very much for your fast and correct reply. That is the movie ...and just look at that movie name =D I would of never found it in a million years. Honored.
